# List of strings to numeric labels

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings and I need to convert it to a list of numeric labels. Example:

```
x= ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']
# output should be something like this:
y=[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3]
```

NB. The list has 100K strings, and I am reading it from a file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
x= ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']
count = 0
for i in x:
  if i not in d:
     d[i] = count
     count += 1

new_x = [d[i] for i in x]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: Nice! This is the only solution that matches the intended idx's.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large array then [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) has an optimised method to do this using [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
In[124]:
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
x= ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']
le.fit(x)
y = le.transform(x)
y

Out[124]: array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

This returns a numpy array from which you can do other operations with and is compatible with the `scipy` stack

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']

vals, ids, idx = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

print(idx)

array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @EdChum, Thanks, I wouldn't be surprised if `sklearn` fundamentally leans on `np.unique` (it seems to be used in lots of places).

Comment: I am happy, and I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution with an intermediate dictionary:

```
x = ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']

d = dict(zip(set(x),range(len(set(x)))))
y = [d[i] for i in x]

print(y)  # [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note: it works if you do not need to order the numeric labels, i.e. if you do not need to associate 0 to the first item in `x`, 1 to the second item in `x`, etc...

**EDIT after comment from Patrick Artner**:
He suggests to precompute the set and store it as own variable, for optimization, and he is right. Here is the updated code:

```
x = ['hello', 'John', 'hi', 'John', 'hello', 'pumpum']

s = set(x)
d = dict(zip(s,range(len(s))))
y = [d[i] for i in x]

print(y)  # [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: you should precompute the set and store it as own variable - you are creating two sets from 100k items each - once to use it inside zip, once just to get the length of it, otherwise nice one +1